# Visual Studio crashes - Newtonsoft.json Bower error

Tags: json, bower, visual-studio-2015

I am using VS Community 2015, but when I try to open a project using bower (containing bower.json), VS crashes. The event log error and bower.json code is shown below. When I rename bower.json, the project will open and run just fine. The same bower.json file works fine on other computers.

I have already uninstalled and reinstalled VS (with all updates) and Bower. Any suggestions to get it from not crashing? Thank you!

Event Viewer Error:

> Application: devenv.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The
>   process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract, Boolean)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader,
>   System.Type, Boolean)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader,
>   System.Type)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[System.__Canon, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PackageManagement.Bower.BowerCommandService.ReadJsonResult[System.__Canon,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PackageManagement.Bower.BowerCommandService+<>c__DisplayClass32_0+<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask+d__76.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask`1+d__3[[System.__Canon,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PackageManagement.Bower.BowerCommandService+d__33.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PackageManagement.Bower.BowerCommandService+d__34.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PackageManagement.PackageManagementEventsService+d__13.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TaskRunnerExplorer.TaskRunnerManager+d__63.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TaskRunnerExplorer.TaskRunnerSolutionEventsManager+d__20.MoveNext()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__6_0(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)    at
>   MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr,
>   IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)    at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr,
>   Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate,
>   System.Object, Int32)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object,
>   System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
>   System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)

Bower.json

```
{
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-filters": "1.1.2",
    "angular-sanitize": "*"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.4.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this error too on my VS2015 with update2 and found the following:

John Montgomery from MS wrote an article with a KB link to add additional fixes for VS update 2 here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/05/06/14-reasons-to-download-visual-studio-2015-update-2-today/

I will be installing this tomorrow on my work computer to see if this fixes the bower crashing VS 2015 problem. Fingers crossed.